# AutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString() is null

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have a drop down AutoCompleteTextView in an action bar.

I am attempting to get text from the AutoCompleteTextView and store it into a string.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location2);//Location2 is my layout

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, null);//location is my custom action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
    Global global = new Global();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, global.getUniversities());
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.searchLocation);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
 ...
}
```

---

```
 public void changeLocation(View view){

    View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.location, null);
    AutoCompleteTextView searchLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            v.findViewById(R.id.searchLocation);
    String searchLocationText = searchLocation.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, searchLocationText,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ...
 }
```

---

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/searchLocation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

The autocomplete feature works like a charm... But the toast shows that String searchLocationText is empty...

What is incorrect about the autocompletetextview in the actionbar?

How can I get the text into a string?

Edit:- More details

I am able to type in the AutoCompleteTextView, it autocompletes with a drop down list and everything is working fine. But I try to turn that information into a string and the string is empty...

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Error refers to line:

```
String searchLocationText = searchLocation.getText().toString();
```

Comment: You're inflating a completely new, different `AutoCompleteTextView` in the `changeLocation()` method, and trying to get text from that. I'm not sure what `view` is in `onCreate()`, but it's not what you're inflating and finding that `AutoCompleteTextView` in in `changeLocation()`.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense! let me see if I can edit my program accordingly, if that is the answer then I'll let you know

Comment: You ommited too much code. How do you get `view` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: You're right.. I just realized that the view onCreate is not the same as the one with the AutoCompleteTextView. I'll Update my question again with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the text from the view you have attached to your layout. But you're inflating a new view here.

```
public void changeLocation(View view) {
    View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.location, null);
    AutoCompleteTextView searchLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            v.findViewById(R.id.searchLocation);
    String searchLocationText = searchLocation.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, searchLocationText,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    [...]
}
```

Instead find the view on the activity like in `onCreate()`

```
public void changeLocation(View view) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    view = actionBar.getCustomView();
    AutoCompleteTextView searchLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.searchLocation);
    String searchLocationText = searchLocation.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, searchLocationText,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Uh oh ... Null object reference. I will post the error hang on

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your time and patience